# Get total issued coins in the Ecosystem

Tags: corda

I am trying to get my total balance of coins that are issued by me i.e.
 ( Node A ) in the entire corda ecosystem/network of nodes, is there an easy method to get all coins `.issue` minus `.exit` that was generated by me? I have thought of two possibilities for workarounds but do not like the designs for both:-

1. take the `transaction.snapshot` and loop through the whole list to obtain the transactions that was self-issued ( `cash.state` & `command.issue` ) minus off the `command.exit` for my own vault, however I don't prefer this approach due to the number of records to go through and the looping mechanisms in place, adding on the pagination aspect to continually loop or to extend the page problem.
2. query all nodes for the current balance including myself and do a summation of total balance. which would be similar to [link](https://github.com/project-ubin/ubin-corda/blob/2f778f9214b498673df9a98d6d6a91632c47129c/account/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/demos/ubin2a/account/AccountFlows.kt#L55), however this would lead to misleading total balance if any other party in the network self-issued some cash of the same currency, adding on the subflow of `ReceiveStateAndRefFlow` have no timeout session where it would wait for a node to come alive indefinately.

Any advices/comments for this issue? Responses are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One other way might be to create a balance state who's sole purpose is to keep a running count of issuances and exits - every time you issue new cash/exit cash, you would update the balance state.

This should then serve as a quick reference point as to how much cash there is.